# Scrollbar style is not working after the new Chrome update?

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

I have the following code that stopped working after the new Chrome update. How can I achieve cross-browser scrollbar styling?

```js
// Note: Shared Scrollbar Style
const scrollbarSharedStyle = {
  scrollbarColor: `${themeLayers.scrollBar[0]} ${themeLayers.scrollBar[1]}`,
  '&::-webkit-scrollbar, & *::-webkit-scrollbar': {
    backgroundColor: `${themeLayers.scrollBar[1]}`,
    width: 12,
  },
  '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb, & *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: `${themeLayers.scrollBar[0]}`,
    minHeight: 24,
    border: `2.5px solid ${themeLayers.scrollBar[1]}`,
  },
  '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:focus, & *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:focus': {
    backgroundColor: `${themeLayers.scrollBar[0]}`,
  },
  '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active, & *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active': {
    backgroundColor: `${themeLayers.scrollBar[0]}`,
  },
  '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover, & *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover': {
    backgroundColor: `${themeLayers.scrollBar[0]}`,
  },
  '&::-webkit-scrollbar-corner, & *::-webkit-scrollbar-corner': {
    backgroundColor: `${themeLayers.scrollBar[1]}`,
  },
};
```

Comment: how is anything `-webkit-` *cross browser*?

Comment: as of Chrum 121, use the *standard* `scrollbar-color` **property**

Answer (score 1):

Chrome 121 update [included the support for `scrollbar-width` and `scrollbar-color` properties](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-chrome-121#css-updates), which, when used, disable `::-webkit-scrollbar` type of properties, according to [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar).

[MDN note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGz4e.png)

The fix is to wrap the use of `scrollbar-width` and `scrollbar-color` with `@supports not selector(::-webkit-scrollbar) {}`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to find the css "scrollbar-width" and "scrollbar-color".
Don't apply them to Chrome.

You might consider

```css
@supports(-moz-animation-delay: 0) {
 .my-element {
   scrollbar-width: thin;
  }
}
```